# Print array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array output using `print_r(array_values($arr))`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 1
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [kjennemerke] => DN 45034
            [kjennemerkeFarge] => SORT
            [etternavn] => RAMBERG
            [fornavn] => BJØRN
        )
)
```

How can I access the `stdClass` object in `$arr[3]` and print each element?

Comment: `echo $arr[3]->kjennemerke`.

Comment: @MarcB: I think Bjorn wants to list all object properties without actually knowing which of them the object contains.

Comment: yes, and that's the basic syntax to access anything. foreach() will iterate the object like it will any other "array"-type structure.

Comment: @MarcB: That's what I meant. That your example didn't explain the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You array is already printed?
The object contains:

```
(
        [kjennemerke] => DN 45034
        [kjennemerkeFarge] => SORT
        [etternavn] => RAMBERG
        [fornavn] => BJØRN
    )
```

If you want to loo trough your object you can do something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($arr[3] as $k => $v):
    echo "Key:".$k."<br>";
    echo "Value:".$v."<br>";
endforeach; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the stdClass element, you can do the following:

```
foreach($array['stdClass'] as $val) {
    echo $val."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with `$arr[3]` you can access to the element you are looking for. now you can use a `foreach` loop to print each element of the object. try with:

```
foreach($arr[3] as $element) { 
  echo $element . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the stdClass items, and print them.

```
foreach( $array[3] as $key => $value )
{
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

If you don't know which item in the array is the object you could do this:

```
foreach( $array as $item )
{
    if ( $item instanceof stdClass )
    {
        foreach( $item as $key => $value )
        {
            echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

If you have more than one stdClass object in the array it will do it for all these objects.